# CountDownTimer run on main thread

Tags: android, timer, textview

I implemented an app, inside there's a button to start a `CountDownTimer` and a TextView to display time left. Someone told me that the timer should run on other thread rather than on main thread, but as I start the timer normally, it 's on the main thread :

```
_timer = new CountDownTimer(min * 60000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tick();
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
                clearChanged();
                Log.v("THREAD TIMER : ", "" + Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                end = true;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
                clearChanged();
            }
        };
```

I use an Observer to update the TextView each time the timer tick, and the code which update the TextView, is also run on the main thread (I confirm it with `Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName()`). But it didn't affect the TextView at all, but it did print out the debugging that I put to test. Anybody have any idea to fix this ?

---

Now this is even more confused. I extract the timer part, and formed a new project. Now, it worked. But of course it still didn't work on my actual project :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    long TIME = 60000;
    CountDownTimer _timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2);

        final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_2);



        setUpButton1(b1, t1);
        setUpButton2(b2, t2);
    }

    private void setUpButton2(final Button b2, final TextView t2){
        final MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
        Observer ob = new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
                //t2.setText(myTimer.toString());
                t2.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        t2.setText(myTimer.toString());
                    }
                });
                Log.v("CLASS TIMER :", Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName() + " thread -- " + myTimer.toString());
            }
        };

        myTimer.addObserver(ob);


        b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    if(b2.isPressed()){
                        b2.setPressed(false);
                        myTimer.stopTimer();
                    }else{
                        b2.setPressed(true);
                        myTimer.startTimer();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpButton1(final Button b1, final TextView t1){

        b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    if (b1.isPressed() == true){
                        b1.setPressed(false);
                        _timer.cancel();
                    } else {
                        b1.setPressed(true);
                        _timer = new CountDownTimer(TIME, 1000) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                t1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                TIME = millisUntilFinished;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {

                            }
                        };
                        _timer.start();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Timer class :

```
public class MyTimer extends Observable{
    CountDownTimer myTimer;
    long TIME = 60000;

    public MyTimer(){

    }

    public void startTimer(){
        myTimer = new CountDownTimer(TIME, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TIME = millisUntilFinished;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
                clearChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };
        myTimer.start();
    }

    public void stopTimer(){
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "" + TIME/1000;
    }
}
```

Anybody have any idea what happened here ? Why it worked in this case, but not work when it's in the whole project ?

Comment: AsyncTask? It gives you even the update-methods that run updates on UI Thread automatically.

Comment: what is `tick()`? what is `setChanged`? what is `notifyObservers`?

Comment: Thanks, I wanna know first, is `CountDownTimer` run on main thread when started, is that normal ? Second, when I update `TextView` directly inside the `CountDownTimer.onTick`, it worked, so the problem is not whether I update the `TextView` on main thread or not, so what's the problem ?

Comment: `tick` is a method to update the presentation of the timer (hour, minute, second), it's just some arithmetic calculation. `setChanged` and `notifyObservers` are the methods of the `Observable`, since I wanna used `Observer` to update TextView

Comment: android.database.Observable<T>? or java.util.Observable? or android.databinding.Observable?

Comment: it's `java.util.Observable`